# Not all of a library's refrenced DLLs are copied local when refrencing from another project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, projects-and-solutions

I am trying to work with the LEADTOOLS imaging library, they have a large set of dll's that need to be referenced. The way our design is set up we have a core library that all of our projects are based off of, all of the DLL's that LEADTOOLS needs are loaded to our base library, and they get copied local to it's build path, but when we use our sub projects only some of the DLL's are copied locally (LeadTools.Codecs.dll and LeadTools.dll to be specific).

There is no difference in settings between the two dll's that are comming over and the 45 that are 
not. What do I need to do to make those codec dll's come over to be copied locally?

> Top half of reference list

[image]

> Bottom of reference list and 2nd project

[image]

> output directory for core

[image]

> output directory for 2nd project

[image]

This is the ItemGroup section from the csproj file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Abc">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Abc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Ani">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Ani.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Bmp">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Bmp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Cal">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Cal.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Clp">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Clp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Cmp">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Cmp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Cmw">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Cmw.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Eps, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Eps.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Fax, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Fax.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Flc, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Flc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Gif, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Gif.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Hdp, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Hdp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Ica, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Ica.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Iff, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Iff.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Img, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Img.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Itg, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Itg.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.J2k, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.J2k.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Jb2, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Jb2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Jbg, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Jbg.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Lma, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Lma.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Lmb, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Lmb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Mac, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Mac.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Mng, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Mng.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Msp, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Msp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Pcx, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Pcx.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Png, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Png.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Pnm, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Pnm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Psd, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Psd.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Ptk, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Ptk.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Ras, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Ras.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Rtf, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Rtf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Sgi, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Sgi.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Smp, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Smp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Tfx, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Tfx.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Tga, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Tga.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Tif, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Tif.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Wfx, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Wfx.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Wmf, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Wmf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Wpg, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Wpg.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Xbm, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Xbm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Xpm, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Xpm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.xps, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.xps.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Leadtools.Codecs.Xwd, Version=16.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\LEAD Technologies\LEADTOOLS Imaging 16.5\Redist\DotNet\x64\Leadtools.Codecs.Xwd.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Specifying `Copy Local` in the reference properties window doesn't work?

Comment: @James Johnson They all have Copy Local set to true. It defaults to true, if it was set to false or had been set to false and set back to true they would have a `<private>` tag in the xml. And setting it to false and settting it back to true so it has the tag is `<private>true</private>` the dll still does not show up.

Comment: I believe you need to edit the publish settings. Make sure they are not prerequisites, but are included.

Comment: Have you tried just copying the DLLs to the BIN folder of your project, and updating the references?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory As this is a project type of Library instead of Console or Windows application there is no publish setup in the configuration.

Comment: @James Johnson That is similar to what I have as a patchwork solution, but I would like to see if anyone has a better solution than what you suggested.

Comment: Can you register the assemblies in the GAC? That will eliminate the need to copy the references locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio has a quirk whereby it doesn't copy dlls to the bin folder if they exist in the GAC. This is true even if you set the assembly to copy local.

To get around it (assuming this it what you are experiencing), you'll need to create a custom build action to copy them over. Alternatively build the project on a server where dlls do not exist in the GAC.