# Does RazorEngine require MVC3 to be installed?

Tags: templating, razorengine

I am working on a web project that uses MVC2. I decided to try out [RazorEngine](http://nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine) to do some e-mail templating. This appeared to work fine when I was protyping using an MVC2 project so I assumed that RazorEngine will work fine for my e-mail templating solution. What I had forgotten at the time was that I actually had MVC3 installed on my local development machine.

After deploying the project on a pre-test server I get the following error in the logs when the application attempts to do anything with RazorEngine:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>
> at RazorEngine.Compilation.DefaultCompilerServiceFactory.CreateCompilerService(Language
>   language)
>
> at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate, Type modelType)
>
> at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate[T](StringrazorTemplate, T model)
>
> at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse[T](String razorTemplate, T model)
>
> at RazorEngine.Razor.Parse[T](String razorTemplate, T model)
>
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
>
> at Persistence.Utility.RazorEngineHelper.Parse(String templateName, Object model) in ...

The fact that it can't find 'System.Web.Razor' means that this DLL does not exist on the deployed server. The only difference I can think of between the deployment server and my local dev machine is that the deployment server does not have MVC3 installed but I may be mistaken because the deployment server is not something I normally control and as such I don't have a lot of information about it. It is meant to host this particular application so there have been previous deployments of this application to this server. This is the first time I'm making a deployment with RazorEngine as a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.Web.Razor dll is deployed with RazorEngine, can you verify it is in you `\bin` directory?

Comment: Thanks! This is true. I have checked the bin directory of my web project and the 'System.Web.Razor.dll' is not there. My web project has a project reference to another project B and project B is the one that references RazorEngine. Upon inspecting the bin directory of project B I can see both DLLs but my main web project only has 'RazorEngine.dll' in the bin and not 'System.Web.Razor.dll' which is why I would have got the error above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ahh I just came across this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433764/not-all-of-a-librarys-refrenced-dlls-are-copied-local-when-refrencing-from-anot). This must be why the 'System.Web.Razor.dll' is not being copied over to the main web project.

Answer (score 0):

I think Razor syntax/view engine first appeared in MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Solution is to put the required version of System.Web.Razor.dll into the same folder with RazorEngine.dll.

If you do so, RazorEngine.dll and System.Web.Razor.dll will be copied to the destionation.